# DNN: Add Querystring parameter to each statically created page in dnn

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, querystringparameter

I want to build pages and menu part of the site statically, But I need to write a module for each page that behaves differently in different pages, So I need to set a querystring parameter for each statically added page, so that the dynamic module can pick this querystring parameter to show a different content on each page.

This querystring parameter should be included in dnn:menu bar links.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you want to add a specific querystring that would be different for each page of the menu to be rendered as part of the menu.  You cannot do this with auto-created pages within the menu system directly.

You COULD edit the template and add something as part of the rendering with you custom elements, but it doesn't sound like that would get you what you are looking for.

Most likely in this case you would need to create your own menu structure, however, I'd question the utility of this behavior if it is added to all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure what you need, but when you are on a particular page, TabId will identify it.